# Laravel boot variable is undefined in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have variable sets all my views in `AppServiceProvider` when I use that variable in the controller it says:

> Undefined variable

## Code

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $ProductSettings = ProductSetting::all();
    foreach($ProductSettings as $psetting){
      $show_unavailable = $psetting->show_unavailable;
      $show_quantities = $psetting->show_quantities;
      $product_pagination = $psetting->pagination;
      $max_short_desc = $psetting->max_short_desc;
      $allow_delivery_time = $psetting->allow_delivery_time;
      $addtocart_on_attribute = $psetting->addtocart_on_attribute;
      $outofstock_lable = $psetting->outofstock_lable;
      $product_orderby = $psetting->orderby;
    }

    $view->with('show_unavailable', $show_unavailable);
    $view->with('show_quantities', $show_quantities);
    $view->with('product_pagination', $product_pagination);
    $view->with('max_short_desc', $max_short_desc);
    $view->with('allow_delivery_time', $allow_delivery_time);
    $view->with('addtocart_on_attribute', $addtocart_on_attribute);
    $view->with('outofstock_lable', $outofstock_lable);
    $view->with('product_orderby', $product_orderby);
});
```

**Controller**

```
//codes...

$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($slug) {
  $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->paginate($product_pagination);

//codes...
```

Based on my database values `product_pagination` is set to `12` which means my code is like: `->paginate(12);`

## Question

**Any idea why I get undefined error?**

## Update

`table`

[image: one]

Comment: Not sure, but maybe because `$view->with` doesn't give the controller the variable?

Comment: "_View composers_" sound like they'd only make variables accessible in ... views. Do you run that query in a view?

Comment: @kerbholz some of my variables i run in views this pagination specifically i need to run in controllers

Comment: @JustCarty do you have any better idea instead of I making same loop in each one of my controllers?

Comment: Also, your model loop in AppServiceProvider doesn't appear to make much sense because you set the variables in the loop, but only assign them to the view after the loop meaning only the last occurence (last row) is used...

Comment: Make them available in a "parent" controller, extend your controllers from that controller to have them available in each of your controllers

Comment: @JustCarty To answer first question: it make sense as my table gets only 1 row, To answer second question I'll update my question for you.

Comment: @kerbholz how...?

Comment: @JustCarty updated. `PS` this table never gets row 2, it only gets updates(edit) even can't be deleted so making loop of it make sense to me because in that way I only use simple variable in blade something like `<php wp_title ?>` in wordpress.

Comment: Which variable does the error say is undefined?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson at the moment `product_pagination`

Comment: No need to loop then... Just set `ProductSettting::first()` to a variable and then access that. E.g. `$psetting = ProductSetting::first();` then `$view->with('show_unavailable', $psetting->show_unavailable);`

Comment: @JustCarty yet giving the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I am going to assume this will work:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->paginate(ProductSetting::first()->pagination);
```

Since you are only ever having one row in your `product_settings` table you can simply access the first row of that table, from there you can access any columns you need.

---

#### Edit 1

Based on the response, apparently the above is "too long".
The only other alternative I have for this question is the following:

```
App::singleton('product_settings', function () {
    return ProductSetting::first();
});
```

Write this method within the `AppServiceProvider` (or any provider of your choice), within the `boot` method.

Then, this can then be used *anywhere* with the following code:

```
app('product_settings')->pagination;
// or, more simply:
app('product_settings')-><some column name>;
```

If you think that there is *still too much* code then you can register your original variables using the same format with the `singleton` method and just add the `-><some column name>` after the first method call.

---

#### Edit 2

The above edit doesn't do anything different from the original solution and will still query with each call to the `app` method.

If you want to keep the database calls to one per controller, then you can store the `ProductSetting::first()` onto the BaseController:

```
class BaseController extends \Controller
{

    protected $product_settings;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Fetch the Site Settings object
        $this->product_settings = ProductSetting::first();
    }

}
```

Then within every controller you can call `$this->product_settings->pagination`.

Comment: I know it can be happen in that way, the reason I was trying to get the value in `AppServiceProvider` was to avoid including my model to all controllers that I need this value and having long  codes such as `ProductSetting::first()->pagination` do you have solution to get this value with simple variable only?

Comment: this `singleton` should I use it in appserviceprovider or creating new middleware etc.?

Comment: @mafortis Out of interest, which of the three methods did you go for? Edit 1?

Comment: currently I'm using solution 1 for 2 reasons: `1` I've read `singleton` in some cases will will return values repeatedly like **foo** will be **foooo** `2` I've read as well is not a good idea to pass variables into basicController as laravel provided view share for the very same reason. `PS` apparently viewShare is only works for blade templates and not controllers.